# class method on active records query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given I have a model/table with appointments, saved as a date. I want to create a method which returns me only active records. One for all records, one on an object. Is my approach improvable/combinable? Thx for advise!

```
def self.actives
  where("start_time >= ?", Date.today)
end

def is_active
  where("start_time >= ?", Date.today)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scopes are the proper way to handle your first filter. See doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html

Your second filter won't work, replace with:

```
def is_active?
  start_time >= Date.today
end
```

I can't see why you want to combine both methods.

Be aware that:

- Model.actives will provide you with an ActiveRecord Relation. You have to append .all to trigger the call. Then you'll have an array to iterate.
- instance.is_active? will provide a boolean